# Golang proto file management and importing

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have 2 grpc services (`service1` and `service2`) that interact with each other and on some cases the rpc response of `service1` will consists of a struct defined in `service2`, after going to several situations where duplication is inevitable, i figure that as the services grow these will be hard to manage, so i restructure the proto files into something like this for now

```
.
├── app
...
├── proto
│   ├── service1
│   │   ├── service1.access.proto 
│   │   ├── service1.proto
│   ├── service2
│   │   ├── service2.access.proto
│   │   └── service2.proto
│   └── model
│       ├── model.service1.proto
│       └── model.service2.proto
└── proto-gen // the protoc generated files 
    ├── service1
    │   ├── service1.access.pb.go
    │   └── service1.pb.go
    ├── service2
    │   ├── service2.access.pb.go
    │   └── service2.pb.go
    └── model
        ├── model.service1.pb.go
        └── model.service2.pb.go
```

`service1` needs to import the model definition on `model/model.service2.proto`, so i am importing it like this

```
import "model/model.service2.proto";

option go_package = "proto-gen/service1";
```

and i generate the `.pb.go` files, using this `protoc` command

```
ls proto | awk '{print "protoc --proto_path=proto proto/"$1"/*.proto --go_out=plugins=grpc:."}' | sh
```

the command generates the `.pb.go` files just fine, but the code on `service1.access.pb.go` doesn't seem to import the model correctly, and i don't know if it related or not but when i run the app, it throws this error

```
cannot load model: malformed module path "model": missing dot in first path element
```

i spent a few hours now googling on how can i properly import another proto file, i can't seem to find any solution

Answer (score 1):

The reason you got that error about `model` is because the generated files use the `go_package` of the imported file, and `model` is not a valid import path. You have to convince the generated file to use the full import path of the package.

This is how I did it for my source tree: I have a similar tree of proto files importing each other. If your module is named, say `github.com/myapp`, then run `protoc` with `--proto-path=<directory containing github.com>`, import other proto files using full path, that is `github.com/myapp/proto/service1/service1.proto`, and in service1.proto, define `go_package = service1`. This setup writes the import paths correctly in my case.

Before settling into this solution, I was using `go_package=<full path to proto>`, so you might give that a try as well.

Comment: ok let me try your first solution real quick. i have tried `go_package=<full path to proto>` approach before  but apparently its creating the full path folders inside my `proto-gen` folder, i might have missed something along the way, but that solution doesnt seem to work

Comment: There was a reason I settled into this solution. I do not remember the reason. That might be it.

Comment: i am on bitbucket, can i use bitbucket instead of github?

Comment: ok is it like this `ls proto | awk '{print "protoc --proto_path=bitbucket.org/myapp/proto bitbucket.org/myapp/proto/"$1"/*.proto --go_out=plugins=grpc:."}' | sh` ?

Comment: Use the fullpath you use to import the go package.

Comment: What I meant is, -proto_path should point to the root of the tree, that is, if you're running protoc under bitbucket.org/myapp/proto, then --proto_path=../../..

Answer (score 1):

Building on Burak Serdar, I want to provide my implementation.

Set the package on the proto you want to import similar to this where the location is your full path. My path is generally `github.com/AllenKaplan/[project]/[package]/proto/`

`option go_package = [path];`

In the file you wish to import to add an import. My path is generally `[package]/proto/[package].proto`

`import = [path from protoc proto path]`

The last part is the protoc command where *you must define the protopath in a way that connects the import path and option go_package path*

if executing from the `github.com/AllenKaplan/[project]` directory, I would call

`protoc -I. --go_out=./[package]/proto [package]/proto/[package].proto`

`-I. === --proto_path.`

the `-I.` sets the protopath to the entire project

---

One note, when calling `protoc` on your `.proto` files that you are importing, you will want to add `source_relative:` to the output will ensure the output is from the root with a set package.

My implementation of the imported protoc when called from `github.com/AllenKaplan/[project]/[package]`

```
protoc -I./proto --go_out=paths=source_relative:./proto [package].proto
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing a similar issue while importing. Had changed the .protoc file option package with the following.

```
option go_package = "./;proto-gen/service1";
```

1. The first param means relative path where the code you want to generate.
2. The path relative to the --go_out , you set in your command.